# Could plants exist on a planet with only 12% of its surface covered by water?

Tags: internal-consistency

Would there be sufficient rainfall on my planet, Zavnious for plants, animals and intelligent beings to exist if only 12% (+-159,000,000km2) of its surface is covered in water, if the planet has a surface area of 1,290,031,236 km2?
The planet has a landscape similar to Monument Valley in the US.
Early on in the planet’s history a larger portion of the planets surface was covered by water, this changed during a period of tectonic upheaval, this exposed many of the planets large cave systems which subsequently flooded lowering the sea level. This upheaval also released  large quantities of molten material which filled the depressions left by the receding oceans.
Due to the planets exaggerated axiale tilt the planet is plagued by high speeds sandstorms, over millions of years these storms have eroded softer rock around the igneous deposits which shielded the rock below it which formed tall sandstone monoliths. In the areas between these are large open areas. Assuming that the majority of the water is saline, could Zavnious support life?

Comment: Does the entire planet have the environment of one valley in the United States? If you have a single-biome world then you're already disregarding ecology.

Comment: Is likely that in the coast would be some greeny places. This reference [The BIOGEOGRAPHY of the DINOSAURS - Atlas Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elZMoatR078) can help.

Comment: Sorry I ment to say landscape instead of environment.

Comment: Does your planet have groundwater?

Comment: What is the depth of the water table? If your planet has sandstorms, it has sand. If it has sand, sand is very water permeable. No reason why there cannot be abundant water below the surface.

Comment: 12% surface water, and perpetual global sandstorms, are not compatible. The sand that land in the water will stay there, rapidly(in geologic time, a few million years) silting up the ocean until it is just a damp sand flat. P.S. The sandstone mineral could only form under water, you might need to explain what happened to the original water that allowed most of the surface to be sandstone in the first place.

Comment: The sandstorms are not perpetual, they are an annual occurrence, mainly in spring after the frost has  thawed and before the summer rains.

Comment: Is this planet cold ? What's the average temperature.. Monument Valley Arizona is 7 degrees now (november) with a very large difference between summer and winter temperature will not help (any) settling life (like plants), large polar regions could keep some of your scarce water frozen..

Comment: As I said, the planet has quite an extreme axial tilt so there is a relatively large temp difference between summer (30’c) and winter (-5’c)

Answer (score 3):

### Presumably.

By definition, if 12% of the planet's surface is covered in water, liquid water can exist on its surface.  Given no other distinction from Earth, plants should be possible.

An issue that *could* come up is whether the water is salty.  If all the salt of the Earth's seas went in to one much shallower basin, it might be comparable to the [Dead Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Sea), lacking in aquatic vegetation such as [eelgrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zostera).  Or it could be something a little more alien like [Lake Natron](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/images/5465/lake-natron-tanzania)

Despite this, we still have to consider the issue of rain.  While the planet seems like a desert, we *know* liquid water remains.  That means we can assign a vapor pressure to this ocean (even if it is lower due to salt concentration - see [this site](http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/pshapley/genchem1/L17/web-L17.pdf) for more.  If the ocean stays liquid it means there must be at least that much vapor pressure of water on average, at least on that part of the planet, and that vapor pressure, if low, is comparable to what we might see on Earth.

Where the rain falls depends on more specific features of your planet.  There could be quite a long River Iss flowing all the way from your ice cap to a global depression, or perhaps your sea happens be close to a feature, such as a range of high mountains, that wrings water out of the atmosphere and leaves it in a basin nearby.